# What does this sentence mean: "Cologne, with its seven and seventy evil savors, was a posy-bed to it."?

Tags: meaning, sentence

This is a sentence from a book I'm translating, the one before that is "The first thing I met was a regiment of the vilest odors that ever assaulted the human nose, and took it by storm." So, what is the author implying by this "Cologne" sentence?

Comment: What is the original language? 'Cologne' is both the name of a big town in Germany -and- a kind of men's perfume (that actually smells nice).

Comment: It has to be dated English. No one would translate something as a posy-bed these days.

Comment: Thanks for translating. (I guess into Chinese.) @BrianHooper has the right general idea below, even though he phrased it under the impression that the passage was talking about the German city. I'd just like to point out that, if you're trying to do a careful job translating instead of get your word count done, you're going to want to be mindful of the idioms she's throwing around. The first sentence is using martial imagery (regiment, assault) and "take by storm" is a phrase whose Chinese equivalent might have nothing to do with bad weather. The important thing is the war theme...

Comment: ...just like the cologne (香水 or 古龙水)'s "seven and seventy" bad smells is a biblical echo (Matt. 18:22) that's about totality and might be translated as "eighty-eight" or "ninety-nine" if that has more associations with completeness in the language you're translating into (and given the biblical echo will fall on deaf ears anyway)...

Comment: ...but the "bed of posies" should be kept the way that it is, despite how mixed the metaphors start to become (it's not very solid writing), because it's a callback to earlier in the page where she talks about the hospital bed *not* being a "bed of roses".

Comment: Oh right... the "related" bar is a time machine. Nevermind...

Answer (score 3):

The author is implying that Cologne is extremely malodourous (*seven and seventy evil savours* is a poetic way of putting it) but the smell in Cologne is immensely preferable to the niff he is currently describing; by comparison the smell in Cologne is very pleasant: *was a posy-bed [compared] to it*.

Comment: @SarahHsu you can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Sounds like the protagonist was wearing cologne, and the stuff was fullfilling one of its age old purposes: rendering offensive odors less objectionable.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger, could be. I hadn't thought of that. On the other hand, even if you don't find eau-de-cologne the most agreeable scent, it isn't usually said to have _seven and seventy evil savours_.

Comment: @BrianHooper: No, it is. It's from [a passage in Louisa May Alcott's *Hospital Sketches*](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=ZKu7rreRcWoC&pg=PA16) and just preserves the capital to show she knows it's full name is water-of-Cologne. If you've never been around men drenched in the stuff, you can substitute *Axe*: it's not actually unpleasant at all but we still disparage it for cultural and status-affirming reasons.